# Must you always have something in the master point of a belay?

Tags: climbing, knots, belaying, rappelling

When building a belay with a sling, and tying an overhand knot to create a master point, I’ve seen it stated that you must always have something in all the master point loops. I assume this is to stop the knot coming undone. However, when shortening a sling with an overhand knot to, for example, use on an abseil, it seems to be perfectly acceptable to have your abseil device behind the knot and nothing in the end loop. Why the discrepancy? Is it just because in an abseil situation the loop is longer, thus reducing the chance the knot works undone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two situations you compare are not really alike. When you shorten a sling by tying a knot in it, suppose the knot fails -- then the carabiner is still caught in the sling.

Clipping in to the shelf of an anchor is different. In an anchor built out of three pieces, we have 6 strands coming down to the knot. You clip in to the shelf by clipping through one strand from each piece. However, it's effectively random which of the two strands you pick from each piece, because you can't see how they're all threaded through the knot. Depending on which ones you clip in to, you can get different things happening in the case where the knot comes undone. Your biner can either be caught or fall out. (I had to try this with my fingers and a rubber band to make sure I was visualizing it correctly.)

Personally I've never heard this rule stated. It does make at least some sense, but I think the risk is small. When you use an overhand knot in this way, it's a type of offset overhand knot, similar to the offset overhand we use as a bend when joining two ropes together for a long rappel. That is a knot that is secure for safety-critical applications, provided that it's properly dressed and pre-tensioned, and has long tails. The belay anchor is different because it has six strands rather than two, so it's not possible to dress it as neatly. Also, it's pretty common that the loops forming the master point are quite short.

And people may use a figure-eight rather than an overhand, which makes the knot easier to untie after it's been loaded. If you do this, then weighting the shelf without anything in the master point is equivalent to a type of offset figure-eight bend, which is not a safe bend like the offset overhand.

Comment: So, are you saying the need to have something in the master point is only there if you have something clipped in the shelf? That makes sense for the reasons you state.

Comment: By including shelf in my search query I’ve actually found this explanation; “Note: For this system to be solid, you must have a biner clipped through the master point—weighted or unweighted—so there’s no way the knot can come undone.” https://www.climbing.com/skills/learn-this-using-the-anchor-shelf/

Comment: @Darren: *So, are you saying the need to have something in the master point is only there if you have something clipped in the shelf?* Well, if you don't have anything clipped in to the master point, and you also don't have anything clipped in to the shelf, then the anchor isn't being used at all, so its safety is a non-issue.

Comment: @Darren: *"For this system to be solid, you must have a biner clipped through the master point—weighted or unweighted—so there’s no way the knot can come undone."* Yes, I had imagined that this putative reason was understood. My answer is an analysis of whether the reason is valid.

Comment: I don’t think I’d thought it all the way through to that logical conclusion.

Comment: I would strongly discourage using the anchor like this. There is just too much of a risk that you are clipping around 2 strands going to the same piece with the upper carabiner. If that piece fails the carabiner will be clipped to nothing. Just clip everything into the masterpoint. Simple, safe and a lot less room for errors

Comment: @Manziel: I think I'm describing the common practices among the people I climb with and the best practices here in North America as described by the Long and Gaines Climbing Anchors book. Clipping into the shelf is a normal thing to do, and there are good reasons to do it. The reasons include avoiding crowding at the master point and getting a higher point to clip into if desired. You're right that if your anchor only had two pieces, and you messed up in clipping the wrong two strands, it could have the mode of failure you describe. But we normally have 3 pieces and are careful.

Comment: "Being careful" is probably the biggest fallacy in anything related to safety. Murphy is a climber and there have been more than enough incidents with people not being tied in at all, not being tied in correctly, being tied into gear loops, placing but not clipping gear, and so on. In my gym alone there have been 2 incidents with people not being clipped into the auto belay, and the second guy even had to ignore a triangle blocking the footholds at the bottom. Not clipping into the master point adds unnecessary risk and complexity.

Comment: And avoiding crowding the master point is a very weak argument. There are only 2 carabiners, one for the belayer and one for the belay. While there is no single "best anchor setup", this one has an obvious weakness which can be easily avoided

Comment: @Manziel, I can’t see how what you describe could happen. It’s very clear which strands are going to which anchor.